# CruiseControl.NET build fails when SVN is not available

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

We have an SVN repository hosted externally and our build server is currently internal.  Occasionally (probably 1 or 2 times a day) the build server is unable to find the SVN repository due to a network outage, a timeout or some other random reason.  With an externally hosted repository this is hard to avoid, however when it fails to find the SVN repository it fails the build!

I would like to find a way for it to just try again at the next interval and ignore any errors relating to an unfound repository.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have posted my config for reference below.

```
<project name="MyProject" queuePriority="0">
<workingDirectory>C:\RemovedForPost</workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory>C:\RemovedForPost </artifactDirectory>
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>http://RemovedForPost \</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>source</workingDirectory>
  <username>myuser</username>
  <password>*****</password>
</sourcecontrol>
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger name="BuildAMinute" seconds="60" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
</triggers>
<tasks>
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\RemovedForPost</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>C:\RemovedForPost\RemovedForPost.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
    <targets>Build</targets>
    <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
    <timeout>120</timeout>
  </msbuild>
  <nunit>
    <path>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe</path>
    <outputfile>C:\RemovedForPost.xml</outputfile>
    <assemblies>
      <assembly> RemovedForPost </assembly>
    </assemblies>
    <timeout>60</timeout>
  </nunit>
</tasks>
```

Thanks

Comment: Definitely lame.  I have that problem too.  +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correction. All of what you want is in the new settings

[CruiseControl.NET docs](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block)

You can set it to not report a failure until max retries is set. So make max at 3 and set it to only move onto the publisher (ie fail the build) unit it hits the limit. So 1 or 2 misses will be ok, but then 3 fail the build something is wrong.

Comment: Well it would fail only once 95% of the times, only twice in a row the other 5% so that trigger isn't going to be much use to me, but if I can't fix this I'll have to get rid of CC.NET.  With only 1-2 checkins a day we are getting a 50% build fail rate.

Comment: Well, I don't know where you would go. It would seem to be to be a basic priniciple of continuosu integration that if you cant reach the source control server you should fail the build. Is there a system you are thinking of that lets you configure this?

Comment: But if you are having THAT many failures, don't you think you should be addressing the root cause of your problem?  I mean, this happens to me sometimes, but it's usually during scheduled downtime of the SCC provider for upgrades and the like.

Comment: Good question, I don't know yet as I am fairly familiar with CC.NET and haven't had this problem with local repositories, only recently with remote ones, so I haven't tried others.  I'll see if I get any more responses first though as I'd hate to get rid of CC.NET.

Comment: My repository is off site, hosted in another country actually.  I could reduce the errors significantly if I changed the interval from 60sec to 30 mins, but I would rather not.  I am not surprised that 1 out of 1440 web requests fail on our network.

Comment: Mate that's awesome, that documentation wasn't there the last time I searched for it.  Exactly what I needed, though I won't know if it works for a few days it certainly appears like it will.  Thanks!

Comment: np, just remember thats for the latest release so you may have to upgrade ;)